# Can I find out what files are accessible to my OS X sandbox?

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

As [the docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html):

> When a user of your app specifies they want to use a file or a folder, the system adds the associated path to your app’s sandbox.

It also mentions that the sandbox includes "certain directories, including" a few, but there doesn't seem to be any authoritative list.

It also says:

> Powerbox has no API.

Is there a way to get a list of all the files that are currently in my sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

sadly no. you can/have to check each file/folder.